# Visual Studio MSI Setup Installer - Read parameters from file

Tags: parameters, windows-installer

I am developing a "Product Package Manager and Updater" application that will download ClickOnce apps to a specific location a execute some SQL scripts on databases. That app should be wrapped into a MSI Setup Installer. 
MSI can run Installer class that executes some SQL which creates: databases, master user, some system tables if they dont exist, etc. I have already done all that, I just need a lot of parameters which I want to pass to Installer, and it would be great if I could pass them as XML. 
I dont want to rebuild those two projects, I only want to put a dirrefent XML file if I want to set a new product into this "Product Package Manager and Updater". This shoudl be a program that I can pass to another people that will only configure that XML data, not code.
I want this to make as more general as it can be by reading only one config file that contains data such as: product name (one product->many ClickOnce apps & DBs), master username and password, and rest config data...
Any suggetstions what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a custom action and then use that CA to read external data.

Comment: I am aware of Custom Actions, in fact I am using them in the project, but I don't have elegant solution for a location where another user of the Setup can put that external data (XML file). That user would provide a MSI file and that XML file. How to make MSI read that XML, without making end user to copy this to a specific location, it would be nice for MSI to do all the work..